# Annoyed my question was migrated from SO

Tags: discussion, suitable-question, migration

I’m not sure why [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313037/how-do-google-1-widgets-break-out-of-their-iframe/7313430#7313430) needed to be migrated from Stack Overflow. Lots of web-related topics are still considered programming. The question had 5K+ views and *no one* commented that it seemed the question wasn’t relevant on SO.

Honestly, it feels like I should have at least had some say in the matter. Instead, it seems to have been migrated due to the caprice of some privileged user.

The final irony is that, had the question *not* been migrated, it would have resulted in my first-ever golden badge on SO.

Answer (score 7):

It appears as though multiple StackOverflow users [voted for the migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313037/how-do-google-1-widgets-break-out-of-their-iframe?noredirect=1) so [SO Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) would be the best place to inquire about their reasoning.

I believe that the migration reflects the perceived specificity of your question to the Pro Webmasters' domain as opposed to the StackOverflow domain.

From the [StackOverflow Question Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions):

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people
>   who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow
>   questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question
>   generally covers …
>
> ```
> * a specific programming problem
> * a software algorithm
> * software tools commonly used by programmers
> * matters that are unique to the programming profession
> ```
>
> ...
>
> If your question would be of interest to Pro webmasters, ask on Webmasters.

You are correct that there are *many* questions on StackOverflow which might fit either site but there does not appear to be any indication that your question was migrated capriciously.

Comment: While I agree it probably wasn't capricious(if we accept the opinion of the voters), I do think this probably should've stayed on SO, as fundamentally requiring code-rummaging to answer, versus being an "[operational](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)" question. Put otherwise, if Alan had asked "How do I *build* a widget that (seems to) break out of its iframe like the +1 button?" it would probably not have been migrated. Other than wording, I think those two topics are equivalent. The answer would definitely have been pretty much the same.

Answer (score 2):

I could go either way on that one, honestly. Since it's already been migrated and it wasn't technically *wrong* but a matter of interpretation, I'm inclined to leave it be for now.

I think the key decision point is that this was an "explain to me how this HTML and Javascript work" question, with an emphasis on the HTML part. So it wasn't quite as clearly *programmery* as it could have been.

In other words, at what point in that question were you writing code or showing code?

Comment: *In other words, at what point in that question were you writing code or showing code?* – I expected the *answers* to include code and/or references to various security models. I don't think the key was markup, but rather implementation. But yeah, sure.